# Amazon S3 when creating an object it throws a cURL error

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I'm using the latest amazon-version which is 1.5, but why oh why that everytime I'm creating an object it throws a cURL error. Here's the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RequestCore_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #16; cURL error: select/poll returned error (55)' in /home/test123/test.com/amazon/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php:824 Stack trace: #0 /home/test123/test.com/amazon/services/s3.class.php(882): RequestCore->send_request() #1 /home/test123/test.com/amazon/services/s3.class.php(1391): AmazonS3->authenticate('bucket...', Array) #2 /home/test123/test.com/amazon_upload_video.php(41): AmazonS3->create_object('bucket...', 'z6yaissmli.mp4', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/test123/test.com/amazon/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php on line 824
```

I made a researched on how to fix this one it says that I should check the config.inc.php of amazon then changed the

```
'certificate_authority' => false
```

into

```
'certificate_authority' => true
```

Still there's an error. There was also a suggestion to add `'curlopts' => array(CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true),`
when creating an object, but still it fails.

I also let other people from different country upload a file but they are not getting an error, maybe it because of a Server Timezone, since I am from Philippines and I let someone from America tried it. The reason why I concluded that way because I saw something about Server Time when doing a research.

What could be the possible solution for this one?

Any idea, help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you use, but you might try [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was using. That's the version 1.5 (latest-version)

Comment: I already followed that instruction, but still no luck. I did managed to changed CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false but still no luck.